# C-LinkedList Append Function, with Bad Memory Address error

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand why the compiler detects a "Bad Memory error"
To my understanding (`Pointer->next != null`) should get me to the end of the tail, but why when it gets to the last node, it detects an error.

```
void Append(Data* head, char* name, char* lastname) { 
    Data* _newNode = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    std::strcpy(_newNode->name, name);
    std::strcpy(_newNode->lastname, lastname);
    // Iretator
    Data* prt = head;
    if ((*name != '\0') && (*lastname != '\0')) {
        // find the last node in the list:
        //Special Case
        if (*head->name == '\0') {
            std::strcpy(head->name, name);
            std::strcpy(head->lastname, lastname);
        } else {
            while ((int*)prt->next != NULL) {
                prt = prt->next;
            }
            prt = _newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: std:: is C++ not C and strcpy is not a member of std! Why do you copy head on prt? Where's the Data structure declaration?

Comment: struct Data{
    char name[10];
    char lastname[10];
    Data *next;
};

Comment: I use a pointer to navigate through the list, and the pointer is pointed to the header to start from there...

Comment: @SergioFormiggini `strcpy` is a member of `std` if `cstring` is included: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy.

Comment: Ok! I didn't know that ... Thanks @Alan Stokes, I'm a C programmer more than C++ ... But I like C++! ...

Comment: prt->next don't need the (int *) cast! I'm searching the problem ...

Comment: After the while loop `prt` is pointing to the last element, so your last line should be `prt->next = _newNode;`

Comment: The compiler does not pass that line of the code. when it reaches the 0xa75 pointer which points to a null  tail pointer it stops. So, it wont even get to the prt->next=_newNode.

Comment: Sincerely I never seen this compiler error!

Comment: Also be careful if `((*name != '\0') && (*lastname != '\0'))` is false, you have a potential memory leak since you don't free the memory allocated to `_newNode`

Comment: That is what drives me crazy, it is not production code, just a function which in theory should be working. Does this may be caused by the Xcode environment  where I am using to complier the code?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the mix of C and C++ here.
One major problem is that you forgot the line

```
_newNode->next = NULL;
```

after creating a new node with malloc and initializing name and lastname.
Without that, your while loop is not guaranteed to work as intended.

The other major problem is at the end of the function after the while:
The while loop loops until ptr->next == NULL. So it points to the last entry.
And you want to append the new node to the last entry.

```
ptr = _newNode; // <<-- WRONG!
ptr->next = _newNode; // this is what you need.
```

Apart from that, your code is not written in a robust and solid way.
Here a slightly improved version which contains vital checks.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 10-1
#define MAX_LAST_NAME_LEN 10-1

void Append(Data *head, char *name, char *lastname) 
{
    // Check preconditions:
    if (NULL == head)
        return;
    if (NULL == name)
        return;
    if (NULL == lastname)
        return;
    if( 0 == strlen(name) )
        return;
    if( 0 == strlen(lastname) )
        return;
    if (MAX_NAME_LEN < strlen(name) || MAX_LAST_NAME_LEN < strlen(lastname))
        return; // too long name or lastname

    // implementation

    // Try to re-use an empty head node.
    if (*head->name == '\0')                        // alien code, covering up for 
    {
        std::strcpy(head->name, name);              // some flaw in the design or other 
        std::strcpy(head->lastname, lastname);      // functions
        return;
    }

    // we need a new one.
    Data *_newNode = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));   // can return NULL, not checked
    if (NULL != _newNode)
    {
        std::strcpy(_newNode->name, name);              // can overwrite memory
        std::strcpy(_newNode->lastname, lastname);      // can overwrite memory
        _newNode->next = NULL;                          // + _newNode->next not initialized to NULL <-- MAIN ERROR!
        // Iretator
        Data *prt = head;
        while (prt->next != NULL)           // (int*) not needed, not good
        {
            prt = prt->next;
        }
        prt->next = _newNode;                       // + the prt points to the last entry 
                                                        // and the new node is appended.
                                                        // the original code was assigning newNode to ptr.

    }
}
```

Comment: You should allocate the memory for `_newNode` just before the while loop. Otherwise, you might end up with a memory leak if `((*name != '\0') && (*lastname != '\0'))` is false or `(*head->name == '\0') ` is true

Comment: @JérômeLeducq In fact I would remove that "special case" code entirely as it has no business being where it is. Apart of that, you are right.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, its a great improvement of the code, if I was planning to put it on to an ARM ignoring the fact, that it has c++ combined. But, the major question that has been  unanswered is why the complier stops in the while ((int*)prt->next != NULL)? The architecture of the code might me as pro as you wish, may other corner cases could be covered, but the fact that complier does not run any further, makes me wonder why? I will spend more time on this code and keep this post updated. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @user3808477 If that truly is your question, then you should add info like compiler version, target information, ... Omitting that info leads to people look at the code in general.

Comment: Code compiles at win32 and x64 with vs2013, btw. Will check next what clang has to say about it.

Comment: Also compiles on clang++ 3.6 without any warning or problem.